# JTable not showing the column names set in the AS part of the SQL prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I know how to manually set JTable column names, but wondering if there was better way because presently I have a prepared sql statement which selects from DB with column names made to show up as different name using the AS 'New Column Name', but the names in the AS part are not showing up, just the standard DB column names... Is that supposed to work that way or is there a better way apart from manually setting column header names using the getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("NEW NAME") ... ? Thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase your question. I didn't get what you meant by "he names in the AS part are not showing up". Is this problem happening with your query or when you're creating the header of your table?

Comment: Since `JTable` does not feature a constructor which accepts an SQL statement, you probably have some code to create a table. Without that it is hard for us to help you further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResultSetMetaData` method `getColumnLabel()` should provide the text from a given `SELECT AS label`. For example,

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name AS moniker, …");
ResultSet rset = ps.executeQuery();
while (rset.next()) {
    String name = rset.getString(1);
    System.out.println(rset.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1)+ ": " + name …);
}
```